# Android: Not getting values of spinner into edittext

Tags: android, spinner

I have dailog with a `EditText` and a `Spinner`, i am implementing as below

```
spinner1 = (Spinner) dialog.findViewById(R.id.quesspinner);

ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> arrayadapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(activity, R.array.fbquestion,R.layout.textview);

spinner1.setAdapter(arrayadapter); 


logo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            spinner1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            spinner1.performClick();
        }
});
```

Now i am unable to read the value of `Spinner`, i want the text in the `Spinner` to be displayed in my `EditText` . code seems to be fine for me but itz not working.Any help is appreciated

```
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
            View view, int pos, long id) {
         int Text = parent.getSelectedItemPosition();
           edittext.setText(Text);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `spinner.getSelectedItem()` instead of `parent.getSelectedItem()`

Comment: i changed to spinner.getSelectedItem() still itz not working..in the log also itz not showing

Comment: @teekib : `itz not working` mean ? app is crashing, any compile time error ?

Comment: it compiling but iam not getting any value into edittext or log when selecting the items in spinner...no app crash is happening

Comment: @teekib : ok try it as  `String Text =parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString()` and make sure setOnItemSelectedListener is firing

Comment: @Prospeak : no the setOnItemSelectedListener is not firing ..what wrong i am doing?

Comment: @teekib : make sure u are selecting other items instead of default  selected ?

Comment: @teekib Provide proper information either complete code including activity or the trace i.e LogCat. It is not a guessing game to answer your question blindly

Comment: @Pragnani  in log cat is showing nothing about this spinner i am doing theis in fragment here is my code http://pastebin.com/QUECtHVu

Comment: @Prospeak thankyou String Text =parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString()  is working

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to like this

To show content in EditText before changing the spinner then do like this

```
spinner1.setAdapter(arrayadapter); 
edittext.setText(spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString());
```

.

```
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
        View view, int pos, long id) {
     String Text = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();
     edittext.setText(Text);
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


});
```

Comment: i changed to spinner.getSelectedItem() still itz not working..in the log also itz not showing

Comment: you want to show the edittext content on change the value from spinner or show content before also...

Comment: i want to show in edit text after selecting from spinner..initially i have hint in edittext

Comment: each time i change selecting the spinner value itz not changing

Comment: do one thing, just write System.out.println("Testing string "+spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString()); in `setOnItemSelectedListener` and test once whether the string is displayed in your console or not..

Comment: the System.out.println("Testing string "+spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString());  not printing anything